# Como devolver un archivo HTML desde Express Node JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, nodejs, express

Buenas como se encuentran comunidad intento abrir un archivo llamando indexCentral que esta en una carpeta static pero no me deja cual es mi error? hay algun problema que el archivo tenga diseño css? anexo mi codigo

```
const { response } = require("express");

const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.get("/",(req, res)=>{
  res.send('Hello World!');
  
});

app.get("/inicio",(req, res)=>{
  res.send('Hello World!');
  
});

//Para el servicio de archivos estáticos 

app.use(express.static('static'));
```

Comment: En ese código no hay referencia al archivo `indexCentral`.

Comment: pero se supone que al poner la ultima linea de codigo de codigo puedo acceder a todo el contenido dentro la carpeta no? dentro la carpeta se encuntra indexcentral @Triby

Comment: Bueno, no estás colocando la ruta del archivo, además, esa última línea no parece correcta, debería ser algo como: `app.use('/static', express.static('static'));`. Revisa [la documentación](https://expressjs.com/es/starter/static-files.html)